# In Pandas how to update column value in one row based on another column value in another row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update value in a cell based on value in another cell in different row.

My dataframe is given below:

```
OrderId   OrderType   Exch
    P_001       P         NYSE
    P_001_1     C          | | 
    P_002       P          |CHIX|
    P_002_1     C          | |
    P_002_2     C          | |
```

And i want the result to be

```
OrderId   OrderType    Exch

P_001       P          |NYSE|
P_001_1     C          |NYSE|
P_002       P          |CHIX|
P_002_1     C          |CHIX|
P_002_2     C          |CHIX|
```

Using `.loc` i can update same rows but i am not able to find any solution in Pandas data-frame for such an update.

While i ask this question, i am try to split the Order id and search in the data frame to update the Exch values.

Answer (score 1):

If not exist values are missing, use forward filling missing values:

```
df['Exch'] = df['Exch'].ffill()
```

Or use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for new `DataFrame`, groupby by first and second column with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df1 = df['OrderId'].str.split('_', expand=True)
df['Exch'] = df.groupby([df1[0], df1[1]])['Exch'].transform('first')
```

---

```
print (df)
   OrderId OrderType  Exch
0    P_001         P  NYSE
1  P_001_1         C  NYSE
2    P_002         P  CHIX
3  P_002_1         C  CHIX
4  P_002_2         C  CHIX
```

Another idea is get rows with `P`, create Series and `map`:

```
s = df[df['OrderType'].eq('P')].set_index('OrderId')['Exch']
df['Exch'] = df['OrderId'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[0].map(s).fillna(df['Exch'])
print (df)
   OrderId OrderType  Exch
0    P_001         P  NYSE
1  P_001_1         C  NYSE
2    P_002         P  CHIX
3  P_002_1         C  CHIX
4  P_002_2         C  CHIX
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Although in my case ffill may not be useful as i simply do not want to fill the empty cells with values above it. But the split function is something i will try.

Comment: i think there is some error in your command; s = df[df['OrderType'].eq('P')].set_index('OrderId')['Exch']  ...i am getting error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: @KS17 - It is weird, what is `df1 = df[df['OrderType'].eq('P')]` and `print (df1.info())` ?

Comment: my bad, i had a copy paste error. It is working fine. Thanks for your help @jezrael.

Answer (score 0):

```
df= df.ffill(axis = 0) 
print(df)
```

---

```
         a  b     c
0    P_001  P  NYSE
1  P_001_1  C  None
2    P_002  P  CHIX
3  P_002_1  C  None
4  P_002_2  C  None
         a  b     c
0    P_001  P  NYSE
1  P_001_1  C  NYSE
2    P_002  P  CHIX
3  P_002_1  C  CHIX
4  P_002_2  C  CHIX
```

If you would like to do that for the while dateset.